# `cummean()` function from dplyr not providing results as expected

Tags: r, dplyr

I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. So I have this small vector `x` where the long(er) way is giving me the results as expected but `dplyr` `cummean()` is not. I am using version `1.0.0`. I have tried reading documentation and searching other guides online but it's almost non-existant. Is this what is expected of `cummean()`? If yes, what are the values that go into this function for the resulting output?

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- 1:5

# long(er) way
cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)
#> [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0

# dplyr cummean()
cummean(x)
#> [1] 1.000000 1.000000 1.333333 1.750000 2.200000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am almost sure that this is a bug. not even the example for the function documentation does return the correct result. `x <- c(1, 3, 5, 2, 2);
cummean(x);
cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)
`. I would suggest to file a bug report if noone else has an explanation for this strange result.

Comment: @mnist Thanks for confirming. For testing, I ran the same code on version 0.8.5 and it works as expected. I have submitted an issue ticket on their github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this question:

This was a bug in dplyr 1.0.0 which has been solved, see [GitHub tidyverse/dplyr #5325](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5325).

This error does not encounter in dplyr version 1.0.2, currently on CRAN